# Clear value on click but restore it if no changes are made

Tags: jquery

So I have this function:

```
            $(document).on('click', '.clearvalonclick1', function(event) {                          
                $(this).val('');
            });
```

It does half of what I need it to do. Basically what I want to happen is when the user clicks on the text box it clears the value, but if no changes are made in the input the value is restored when the user clicks out.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$(document).on('focus', '.clearvalonclick1', function (event) {
    $(this).data('val', this.value).val('');
}).on('blur', '.clearvalonclick1', function (event) {
    var $this = $(this);
    if(this.value == ''){
        $this.val($this.data('val'))
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/yrg8Q/)

Answer (score 1):

Use `placeholder` attribute for `input` element:

```
<input placeholder="sometext" />
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Xhez/)

Not supported in IE9-, though: http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-placeholder

**EDIT**: JavaScript alternative:

```
var placeholderText = "placeholder";
$('input').val(placeholderText)
    .on('focus', function () {
        $(this).val('');
    })
    .on('blur', function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        if (!$this.val()) {
            $this.val(placeholderText);
        }
    });
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Xhez/1/)